# Building crti.o for i386

Tags: gcc, x86-64, glibc, 32-bit

I am trying to build a cross-compiler with x86_64 being the host and i386 being the target. I'm getting the (all to common) crti.o: No such file error. Instead of grabbing an already built crti.o and crtn.o from a distro... how might I go about building these files explicitly from glibc (or possibly gcc) sources?

FYI, I am well aware of the -m32 option for x86_64 compilers. I'd prefer to just have a 32bit-only compiler environment. Also, the reason I don't want to use any of the gazillion already build i386 compilers is because I plan on mixing and matching glibc/binutils/gcc versions depending on my testing needs.

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: possible duplicate of [crti.o file missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91576/crti-o-file-missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're using configuring the cross-compile correctly?  It should be

```
CBUILD = CHOST = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
CTARGET = i386-pc-linux-gnu
```

as you're running a build on an `x86_64`, for a compiler to run on an `x86_64`, which generates code for an `i386`.

If you used `CHOST = i386-pc-linux-gnu`, you'll be trying to generate 32-bit binaries, which will need to link with a 32-bit `libc`.  Which is fine, if you already have a 32-bit `libc`, but it sounds like you don't.

i.e.

```
$ tar xvjf gcc-*.tar.bz2
$ cd gcc-*/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=i386-pc-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility (from [here](http://webui.sourcelabs.com/gcc/mail/user/threads/libgcc_4.3.0_fails_to_build%253A_crti.o%253A_No_such_file.meta))

> You need to install your distro's 32
>   bit libc-dev package, or you need to
>   --disable-multilib which will result in a compiler that doesn't support 32
>   bit mode.

Comment: I want 32bit only, not the other way around. I do not want to use a distro copy... i want to build from source. Please read the FYI.