# "C compiler cannot create executables" when try to build PROJ.4 library (& rgdal) on MacOS 10.7.2

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, osx-lion

I'm trying to install the PROJ.4 - Cartographic Projections Library (http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/WikiStart#Download) on a Mac OS 10.7.2. I downloaded the .tar.gz file and proceeded to run ./configure.

The process exits with the following errors:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The config.log file contains the following information:

```
/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 2 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
2 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1
Primary memory available: 2.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 129 tasks, 746 threads, 2 processors
Load average: 5.68, Mach factor: 0.30
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
PATH: /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin
PATH: /Developer/usr/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/texbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1995: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2051: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2062: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2105: result: yes
configure:2133: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2172: result: ./install-sh -c -d
configure:2185: checking for gawk
configure:2215: result: no
configure:2185: checking for mawk
configure:2215: result: no
configure:2185: checking for nawk
configure:2215: result: no
configure:2185: checking for awk
configure:2201: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:2212: result: awk
configure:2223: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2244: result: yes
configure:2432: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2441: result: no
configure:2505: checking for gcc
configure:2521: found /Developer/usr/bin/gcc
configure:2532: result: gcc
configure:2770: checking for C compiler version
configure:2777: gcc --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2780: $? = 0
configure:2787: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
configure:2790: $? = 0
configure:2797: gcc -V >&5
gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2800: $? = 1
configure:2823: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2850: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2853: $? = 1
configure:2891: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "PROJ.4 Projections"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "proj"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.7.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "PROJ.4 Projections 4.7.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "warmerdam@pobox.com"
| #define PACKAGE "proj"
| #define VERSION "4.7.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2898: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Since one of the error messages was "ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o", I tried to implement the solution shown here [Error in xcode project: ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365211/error-in-xcode-project-ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt1-10-6-o), specifically by adding the following to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib
```

That did not work and I still get the same problem. Also, the error "error: C compiler cannot create executables" seems to be persistent across many of the things I try. I get the same problem when I try to install the rgdal library in R using the command line.

I would appreciate any and all help!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running Lion but your gcc is configured for `darwin10`, which is Snow Leoaprd.

Did you upgrade from Snow Leopard to Lion without reinstalling Xcode? I would recommend completely uninstalling your old Xcode (run `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools`), then install the latest Xcode from the Mac App Store.

Comment: That's very good to know, thanks a  lot. I just did that and it seems to work fine now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is frequently a problem in your environment. Have you altered $PATH or .MacOSX/environment.plist in any way? Often people do this when following advice given surrounding MacPorts or fink. You might try undoing those changes.

If that's not the problem, upgrading the OS can frequently cause similar symptoms. Be sure you install developer tools after a major OS upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think that's it though, because even though I have edited ~/.bash_profile, clearing that prevents terminal from finding gcc at all (which is located here: PATH=/Developer/usr/bin).

The changes I made to ~/.bash_profile are also necessary to point to the correct frameworks I installed, specifically the Python, GDAL, LaTeX, and R.

Comment: Could this be an issue of upgrading to Lion? I've read some places that can mess things up?

Comment: Yes. Did you reinstall developer tools after upgrading to Lion?

Comment: Great. Updated the answer for easier searching.