# Missing crt1 and crti when crosscompiling

Tags: gcc, linker, cross-compiling

I'am trying to build a cross compile toolchain based on GCC4.5 and newlib with gold and link-time-optimization enabled. GCC compiles fine but it did not generate the crt1.o or crti.o files. Therefore when I tries to use the compiler for building Newlib it complains with the message:

```
ld: error: cannot open crti.o: No such file or directory
ld: error: cannot open crtn.o: No such file or directory
ld: error: cannot find -lc
```

When searching for files named crt* in the directory where GCC4.5 is installed i got the following result:

```
find ../../../tooltarget/ -name "crt*" -print #(result modified to consume less space)
crtprec80.o, crtend.o, crtfastmath.o, crtbegin.o, crtendS.o, crtprec32.o, crtbeginS.o, crtbeginT.o, crtprec64.o
```

From the GCC spec's it seems like gcc needs both the crtbegin.o and the crti.o files, but only one of them is available.

```
*startfile:                                       
%{!shared: %{pg|p|profile:gcrt1.o%s;pie:Scrt1.o%s;:crt1.o%s}}    crti.o%s %{static:crtbeginT.o%s;shared|pie:crtbeginS.o
%s;:crtbegin.o%s}
```

Following is the flags i used when compiling GCC:

```
--prefix=${TTP}/usr         --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  --target=x86_64-awn-linux-gnu
--with-gmp=${TTP}/usr       --with-mpc=${TTP}/usr
--with-mpfr=${TTP}/usr      --with-libelf=${TTP}/usr               
--enable-languages=c        --enable-lto                           
--disable-nls               --disable-shared                       
--disable-multilib          --disable-decimal-float                
--disable-libmudflap        --disable-libssp                       
--disable-libgomp           --disable-threads                      
--without-headers           --with-newlib                          
--with-build-sysroot=${TTP} --with-build-time-tools=${TTP}/usr/bin
```

I'm sure on if this is due to I configured GCC wrongly, or "stuff" simply do not work this way, or if the files crti.o should come from somewhere else.

Thanks in advance

Allan W. Nielsen

Comment: possible duplicate of [crti.o file missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91576/crti-o-file-missing)

Comment: I just solved a problem like this with gcc build adding `--host=x86_64` to `./configure` script, but not sure if helps.

Answer (score 1):

Some `crt*` files come not from the compiler, but from the C library. I suspect this is the case here for your `crt1.o` and `crti.o`.

Comment: No, there are ctr1.S and crti.S which are generated by a script during gcc's build time.

Comment: Indeed, GCC uses some scripts for these files. It's not very transparent to most people I guess; at the least it is not to me.