# Cross Compile Cannot Find crt1.o

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

Hi I am compiling Linux from Scratch (www.linuxfromscratch.org) and I am on a step that requires my to compile a test c program to see if the compilation is working and it is failing.
The commands I am using are:

```
echo "main(){}" > dummy.c
$LFS_TGT-gcc -B/tools/lib dummy.c
readelf -l a.out | grep ': /tools'
```

When running the second line, the compiler returns the following

```
..path../bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
..path../bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
..path../bin/ld: cannot find -lc
..path../bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Not sure what the problem is here and how to fix it,
So far I have reinstalled the gcc package as well as the specs file.

The output of `$LFS_TGT-gcc -v -B/tools/lib dummy.c` is:

```
Reading specs from /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/specs
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto- wrapper
Target: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.1/configure --target=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu --prefix=/tools --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-multilib --disable-decimal-float --disable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libgomp --disable-libquadmath --disable-target-libiberty --disable-target-zlib --enable-languages=c --without-pppl --without-cloog --with-mpfr-include=/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-4.6.1/mpfr/src --with-mpfr-lib=/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/mpfr/src/.libs
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-B' '/tools/lib' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1 -quiet -v -iprefix  /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/ -isystem /tools/include dummy.c quiet -dumpbase dummy.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase dummy -version -o /tmp/ccQMiBtT.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.6.1 (x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /tools/include
 /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
 /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.6.1 (x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: ac76a9fc3d8568635f4cf190a73f3235
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-B' '/tools/lib' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/as --64 -o /tmp/ccjUV0Gs.o /tmp/ccQMiBtT.s
COMPILER_PATH=/tools/lib/:/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/:/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/tools/lib/:/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/:/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-B' '/tools/lib' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /tools/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 crt1.o crti.o /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbegin.o -L/tools/lib -L/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1 -L/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc -L/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib /tmp/ccjUV0Gs.o -lgcc -lc -lgcc /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtend.o crtn.o
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I realize that it is super long but if someone would tell what is relevant I will trim it. Because quite honestly I don't know whats useful.

Comment: This can also happen if `--with-lib-path=/tools/lib` is missing because ld won't know to add `-L/tools/lib`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling problems: cannot find crt1.o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

crt1.o, crti.o and crtn.o and libc.a all come with your glibc.

You need to have glibc compiled for your target system and installed, from the looks of it, in /tools/lib.

EDIT: Not necessarily glibc, but whatever libc you're using.

Comment: I already compiled glibc... but ill redo it to see if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help... turns out my problem was calling `make install` without sudo. A fresh install cleaned everything up. Thanks! 50 rep coming your way.

Answer (score 3):

If recompiling gcc is not an option because it is already installed with sysroot, then try this:

```
`export CFLAGS="--sysroot=<your-gcc-sysroot>"`
```

(hint: `libc.so.x` is in `<your-gcc-sysroot>/lib`)

Then edit your makefile and replace any

```
`CFLAGS=BLA-BLA`
`CPPFLAGS=BLA-BLA`
```

with

`CFLAGS+=BLA-BLA`
   `CPPFLAGS+=BLA-BLA`

Answer (score 2):

Pass `-v` to your `$LFS_TGT-gcc` to understand what is happening.

Comment: The -v flag will show you want programs gcc is running, in particular it will show how ld is invoked, so you'll understand what is wrong.

Comment: I posted the verbose output of the command, I'm not sure what part is relevant so I posted it all.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the following problem:

```
root@gccc# arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi-gcc x.c
/opt/tools/wrl3.GA/wrlinux-3.0/layers/wrll-toolchain-4.3-85/arm/toolchain/x86-linux2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
root@gccc#
```

So when I researched it I found out that I was not able to find out the sysroot in the correct path. So I specified the sysroot on the command line and my problem was solved:

```
root@gccc# arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi-gcc x.c --sysroot=/opt/tools/wrl3.GA/sysroot.2011_05_31.18_29_24/arm11_le-glibc_small/sysroot/ -o exe
```