# Installing GCC 4.7.1 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gcc, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install GCC 4.7.1 following [this](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/04/13/building-gcc-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/) very good tutorial. I did (almost) everything by the book, but I get the following error during `make`

```
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile.
```

This is my configure command, the only thing I changed in that tutorial is the file `gcc-4.7.1`, that's all.

```
 ../gcc-4.7.1/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/gcc_4_7 --with 
 gmp=/usr/gcc_4_7 --with-mpfr=/usr/gcc_4_7 --with-mpc=/usr/gcc_4_7 --enable-
 checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-4.7
```

I've looked in Google, and most of the answers seem to point to the way `gcc` loads the includes for `mpfr`, `mpc`, and `gmp`, so I symlinked the folders in the gcc-4.7 directory (I'm building outside the source directory, as per general recommendation).

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `config.log` usually has more detailed information, including the exact failed command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gmp-4.1.3/lib:/usr/local/mpfr-2.3.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, replacing the paths with the location where mpfr and gmp are installed on your machine, if necessary.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "mpfr" and "gpm" you mean `libgmp.so.10.0.5`, that is, the libs??

Comment: Yes, I do. Some versions of GCC have an issue where the `--with-mpfr` and `--with-gmp` flags don't work, but setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH fixes it.

Comment: This was correct. However, there was another problem: crtio.o not found. I'm documenting it here for other people who might be wondering too. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o. Still, this was the right response. Accepted! Thanks.