# GNAT-GPS tutorial link error

Tags: gnat-gps

I am getting a link error when trying to build the sdc tutorial file.  I've installed the gnat gpl using the install script.  And the .o files exist in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.
How do I configure to get the linker to see?  I've tried adding to the path.

here's the output:

```
gnatmake -d -P/home/steve/workspace/ada/tutorial/sdc.gpr -XBuild=DEBUG sdc.adb
gnatbind -static -x /home/steve/workspace/ada/tutorial/obj/sdc.ali
gnatlink /home/steve/workspace/ada/tutorial/obj/sdc.ali -g -o /home/steve/workspace/ada/tutorial/obj/sdc
/usr/gnat/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/gnat/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/gnat/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/gnat/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gnatlink: error when calling /usr/gnat/bin/gcc
gnatmake: *** link failed.
[2013-11-29 08:47:55] process exited with status 4 (elapsed time: 00.21s)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling problems: cannot find crt1.o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o)

Answer (score 0):

This is in general a sign that there was a problem during the installation. Removing your install (/usr/gnat) and reinstalling might fix the issue.
The answer comes late, but hopefully will be useful to someone else seeing the same issue later on.