# Can't compile C code on linux

Tags: c, linux, r, gcc, installation

I am attempting to install rJave / JRI (code that lets you run R commands from within a Java application) on a Linux 13.10 "cloud" / virtual server.

If I try install.packages("rJava") from within R, I get "

> ```
> * installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
> ** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
> checking whether the C compiler works... no
> configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpW6xdRi/R.INSTALLbff775d77a6/rJava':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details
> ```

Unfortunately, I have no idea where config.log is, and `find / -name "config.log"` doesn't find anything.  So I downloaded the source and tried to install:

> ```
> checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
> checking for C compiler default output file name... 
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details.
> ```

Now, at least, I have a config log.  Any explanation on why this is failing would be greatly appreciated:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by JRI configure 0.3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = greg1304
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.8.0-33-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #48-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 09:16:58 UTC 2013

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /home/gregd/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1722: checking build system type
configure:1740: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:1762: checking host system type
configure:1777: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:1910: checking for gcc
configure:1937: result: gcc -std=gnu99
configure:2175: checking for C compiler version
configure:2182: gcc -std=gnu99 --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2185: $? = 0
configure:2192: gcc -std=gnu99 -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-l
anguages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr
/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --ena
ble-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with
-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 
configure:2195: $? = 0
configure:2202: gcc -std=gnu99 -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2205: $? = 4
configure:2228: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2255: gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -pipe -g   conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2258: $? = 1
configure:2296: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "JRI"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "jri"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "JRI 0.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "simon.urbanek@r-project.org"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2303: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -g'
CPICF=''
CPP='gcc -std=gnu99 -E'
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
JAR=''
JAVAC=''
JAVAH=''
JAVA_CFLAGS=''
JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk'
JAVA_INC=''
JAVA_LD_PATH=''
JAVA_LIBS=''
JAVA_PROG=''
JNILD=''
JNIPREFIX=''
JNISO=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='simon.urbanek@r-project.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='JRI'
PACKAGE_STRING='JRI 0.3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='jri'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RINC='-I/usr/share/R/include'
RLD='-L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR'
R_DOC_DIR='/usr/share/R/doc'
R_HOME='/usr/lib/R'
R_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/share/R/include'
R_SHARE_DIR='/usr/share/R/share'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
ac_ct_CC='gcc -std=gnu99'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "JRI"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "jri"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.3"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "JRI 0.3"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "simon.urbanek@r-project.org"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: The fact that the build tries a `-V` flag is interesting, it doesn't exist for me either. It's quite possible their build setup is actually broken, or (hopefully) you've tried to do this with the wrong environment setup...

Comment: @Veltas just looking through the configure script, that issue is rather harmless if I understand the code correctly.

Comment: @GregDougherty have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o - I think that the missing crt1.o & co files is the central issue, there are a couple of possible solutions and workarounds you can try.  However, the rJava version on [GitHub](https://github.com/s-u/rJava) is significantly different from yours, are you sure you have a reasonably recent version?

Comment: @fvu:$ sudo apt-get install libc0.1-dev
Package libc0.1-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
However the following packages replace it:
  libc-dev-bin:i386 libc-dev-bin

E: Package 'libc0.1-dev' has no installation candidate
$ sudo apt-get install libc-dev-bin
libc-dev-bin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: @fvu: Thank you for the pointer to GitHub.  I got mine from rforge, and they're many versions behind http://www.rforge.net/JRI/svn.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your C problems, but I don't think you'll get anywhere if it tests your C++ compiler with those flags - I think that -std=gnu99 is invalid for c++ (although it works with c, hence my assumption you already have some other problem)

Edit:
Also not sure if this is a versioning thing (my gcc is 4.8.1), although I doubt it, but you have a 64bit target but no 64 bit libraries for gcc, as far as I can see? My output for gcc-std=gnu99 -v includes a couple of flags near the bottom, which you have some but not all of:

```
--with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Perhaps your problem lies here, if the program is checking for 64 bit compiled executables (given your system is x64_86?)

Comment: Are you trying to say that Greg is compiling on the wrong architecture?

Comment: @Veltas My suggestion is if the rJava code is picking up a 64 bit arch, it might try a 64 bit compiler, but I can't see any flags indicating that his gcc includes 64 bit libraries. So I guess, yes, although not for the program he's currently compiling.

Comment: Looking at the changelog on Launchpad : [https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=4.7.2-2ubuntu1&field.actions.search=Search] lists a number of issues with headers, but I'd assume these were patches that fixed issues before it became a part of the software center? @Greg, if you don't need that specific version of gcc, you could try getting a different version? Since it looks like you installed the binaries rather than compiled it yourself, it shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes, right?

Comment: Here's what I get when I just run gcc gcc-std=gnu99 -v
gcc: error: gcc-std=gnu99: No such file or directory
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ... --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --libexecdir=/usr/lib --libdir=/usr/lib --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)

Answer (score 0):

So I upgraded for 13.04 to 13.10, and that apparently upgraded my gcc from 4.7 to 4.8.  So I tried again, and this time everything worked.

So I'm going to call this a gcc 4.7 bug.

Thank you for all the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

For reference: on Ubuntu 16.04 you have to install 'libc6-dev'