# How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit RHEL?

Tags: gcc, x86, 32-bit, rhel7

I'm trying to compile a 32-bit C application on RHEL 7 64-bit using gcc 4.8. I'm getting a compiler error `/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory`. What do I need to do to get 32 bit apps compiled and linked?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To get RHEL 7 64-bit to compile gcc 4.8 32-bit programs, you'll need to do two things.

1. Make sure all the 32-bit gcc 4.8 development tools are completely installed:

   ```
   sudo yum install glibc-devel.i686 libgcc.i686 libstdc++-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686
   ```
2. Compile programs using the -m32 flag

   ```
   gcc pgm.c -m32 -o pgm
   ```

Comment: You might also want to mark this answer as a solution to the question.