# Error Compiling GCC on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

While installing `gcc-3.4.6` (I really need only this version) I get this error

```
$ make 1>/dev/null
./unwind-dw2.c: In function `uw_frame_state_for':
./unwind-dw2.c:1031: error: field `info' has incomplete type
make[2]: *** [libgcc/32/unwind-dw2.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [stmp-multilib] Error 2
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375445/error-compiling-gcc-3-4-6-in-ubuntu-14-04), but it does not solve the problem?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox.

Comment: [Error compiling GCC 3.4.6 in Ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375445/error-compiling-gcc-3-4-6-in-ubuntu-14-04) is the exact same error you are getting, so why does the solution in that question not work?

Comment: Why do you need such an archaic version of GCC?  Why do you think it will help when a more modern version won't?  (About the only thing I can think of is it still supports writable strings, so if you have archaic, ill-behaved software to port, maybe you won't get into as much trouble with that software modifying string literals.  But maybe you should fix that code rather than fight to instal GCC.)

Comment: Yes it is but it did not work  tested it before posting.

Comment: Need it to install virtuoso for virtual machine introspection