# cross gcc crti.o

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, ld, clfs

I have followed the instructions at [Cross linux from scratch for powerpc](http://cross-lfs.org/view/svn/ppc/index.html), but I can't get past the `gcc-final` stage due to an `ld` error `crti.o: no such file or directory`.

My tool chain is separated into two directories: `/opt/builder/tools` and `/opt/builder/cross-tools`, with Linux headers and eglibc in the first and cross-utilities in the second. Also I have created links `/tools` and `/cross-tools` for those directories.

I have tried `/cross-tools/bin/powerpc-unknown-linux-gcc -print-search-path` and there was a directory `/opt/builder/tools/lib` there in the "libraries" section. But gcc passes names of `crt....o` objects to `ld` without directory prefixes (I have used strace to find it out).

The `crt....o` files are good because, when I copied them to the directory with `hello.c` and compiled it, everything was ok.

Could you give some advice?

Thanks in advance,

Sergey Naumov.

Comment: possible duplicate of [crti.o file missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91576/crti-o-file-missing)

Answer (score 0):

The libc-provided crt files should be in `$ROOT/$TARGET/lib/` (i.e.,  The gcc-compiled crt files will later be installed in `$ROOT/lib/gcc/$TARGET/$GCC_VERSION/`.