# Building linuxbrew (homebrew) standalone version on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, homebrew, linuxbrew

### The Primary Question

I'm trying to build the [linuxbrew standalone installation](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/wiki/Standalone-Installation) on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, but the script in the original link is currently broken. My ideal answer would be a script that sets it up correctly in one go. I've [improved the script](https://gist.github.com/ahundt/1478c6771d1247b546c4) to run with fewer hiccups.

### Current progress towards fixing the script

I'm not able to get past a `crti.o` error when building gcc via linuxbrew as part of the standalone setup. However, I found some resources explaining the problem:

- [stackoverflow crti.o file missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91576/crti-o-file-missing)
- [stackoverflow cannot find crti.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o)
- [askubuntu crti.o](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251978/cannot-find-crti-o-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [old launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/+bug/738098)

I searched for the file and it was right there!

```
find -name crti.o
./.linuxbrew/lib/crti.o
./.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.19/lib/crti.o
```

I'm currently on the following compiler error for `crtn.o`:

```
/home/hbr/.linuxbrew/Cellar/binutils/2.25.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/hbr/.linuxbrew/Cellar/binutils/2.25.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/home/hbr/.linuxbrew/Cellar/binutils/2.25.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libgcc_s.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gcc20150929-3726-hif3of/gcc-5.2.0/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gcc20150929-3726-hif3of/gcc-5.2.0/build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gcc20150929-3726-hif3of/gcc-5.2.0/build'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

Essentially, at this step I need to figure out how to make sure brew/linuxbrew/the gcc compilation command knows where to find it. I tried adding it to `PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in [the script](https://gist.github.com/ahundt/1478c6771d1247b546c4) all without any luck. So, there must be some other way to make sure the path is set correctly and the object file is found. Any ideas?

Note: I originally searched for help in [this github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/issues/530) but they haven't been able to solve this at the moment.

**Update**

I think a linuxbrew case may be needed in this [linuxbrew gcc formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gcc.rb) that implements one of the solutions found in [stackoverflow crti.o file missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91576/crti-o-file-missing).

This is the original [homebrew gcc formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gcc.rb) for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the [linuxbrew standalone installation](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/wiki/Standalone-Installation) instructions with the solution. I've also created an updated [linuxbrew-standalone.sh](https://gist.github.com/ahundt/1478c6771d1247b546c4) that's tested and working in 14.04 with a couple of small caveats listed below in the `TODO` comments.

```
# /bin/bash
set -e
set -u
set -x

cd $HOME

# TODO: The next ln -s line breaks cross compiling with multiarch, need an alternative!
#       source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004026/99379
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing -y
sudo apt-get install build-essential curl g++ git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev gawk make patch tcl -y

unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH PKG_CONFIG_PATH HOMEBREW_CC
PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
yes | ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

# hang on here. you will have to press return
# note that even if brew doctor is a little unhappy we want to keep going
brew doctor || true

mkdir $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib
ln -s lib $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib64
ln -s $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib64
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib/
PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib:$PATH
export PATH
LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# before this, you may want to `brew edit glibc` to produce compatibility for your particular kernel, for example:
# "--enable-version=2.6.18"

#brew unlink gawk
brew install glibc
brew unlink glibc
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/zlib.rb
brew reinstall binutils
brew link glibc
brew install patchelf
brew install gcc --with-glibc --only-dependencies -v
# When tested gcc was working except for the linking step, that's why it is force-accepted with ||true
# TODO: make it so force accepting isn't necessary and errors are shown correctly
brew install gcc --with-glibc -v || true
rm -f $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib/{libstdc++.so.6,libgcc_s.so.1}
brew link gcc --overwrite
export HOMEBREW_CC=gcc

brew install bzip2 curl expat
brew install git --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl --without-tcl-tk
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install coreutils findutils gawk gnu-sed gnu-which grep libpng libxml2 libxslt make ncurses readline
#ln -s ncursesw/curses.h ncursesw/form.h ncursesw/ncurses.h ncursesw/term.h ncursesw/termcap.h $HOME/.linuxbrew/include/
#ln -s libncurses.a $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib/libcurses.a
#ln -s libncurses.so $HOME/.linuxbrew/lib/libcurses.so
brew install ruby
PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$HOME/.linuxbrew/sbin
brew install hello && brew test hello; brew remove hello
```

The primary line that fixed things was `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64`, but this comes with a caveat for which I'm interested in a fix, because it [breaks cross compiling with multiarch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004026/99379).